# Eclipse - how to disable update dynamic java source working set

Tags: java, eclipse

Any change on project and i get following error:

```
An internal error occurred during: "Update dynamic Java sources working sets".
org.eclipse.jdt.core.IClasspathEntry.isTest()Z
```

[image]

known bug in eclipse. Bug report [see here](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=530297). Bug fixed in M6. 
Any temp solution for M5?
INFO:

```
Eclipse IDE for Java Developers
Version: Photon Milestone 5 (4.8.0M5)
Build id: 20180202-1214
OS: Windows 10, v.10.0, x86_64 / win32
```

Comment: You could use an I-build (Integration, updated weekly) from http://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/downloads/ .

Comment: @Roman C my question is absolute not duplicate with Can't start Eclipse - Java was started but returned exit code=13

Comment: Are you sure that you hit bug 530297 (your link)? The exception there states IllegalStateException. I think this is another one I also hit, and it is not fixed in the least build of Eclipse. Error message is: `java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.eclipse.jdt.core.IClasspathEntry.isTest()Z`

Comment: Would you be able to also post your installed plugins?

Comment: I had this same problem show up this week when I did an update. I don't have a solution, but reinstalling eclipse and plugins from scratch fixed it for me. My details if it's helpful:

Eclipse JEE,
Vrapper,
Team Explorer Everywhere,
Darkest Dark